# SwiftUI macOS MenuButton label issue

Tags: macos, swiftui

I am using a MenuButton in my macOS application. MenuButton takes a label and content as argument, which is working fine. Apple gives following declaration

```
struct MenuButton<Label, Content> where Label : View, Content : View
```

I am trying to use a View with two `Image` and a Text as Label, which looks like the following:

```
MenuButton(label: Title(name: "Title"), content: {
    ...
})
.menuButtonStyle(BorderlessButtonMenuButtonStyle())
```

Title is declared as following:

```
struct Title: View {
    var name : String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack
        {
            Text(self.name)
                .foregroundColor(Color("c_SecondaryColor"))
            
            Image("PickerIcon") //<< This is visible

            Image("PickerIcon2") //<< This is NOT visible - can not use two Image

        }
    }
}
```

In Title I have two Image. However, only one is shown. Why does label only allow one Image, even though it is declared as `View` type.

Comment: Have you tried "Text(...)+Text(Image)+Text(Image)" to create a rich text label?

Comment: @StephanMichels: Only available for SwiftUI 2.0, for which MenuButton is deprecated anyway already.